# How do I write a Qt HTTP GET request?

Tags: c++, qt

I'd like to write a small HTTP `GET` request in C++ but I'm not finding a solution.

Maybe I have to use `QNetworkAccessManager` class but I'm not an expert in C++ and it's really hard to understand something about this class.

I have an URL to fetch, which will give me a JSON response; I have to extract a single key (`key2`) and put the value in a variable. This is an example:

```
{"key1": "value1", "key2": "**value2**", "key3": "value3"}
```

This is my debug code:

```
char value[20]
value = <**value2**>
```

After this I have to print this value in a form .ui

Comment: Show what you've tried.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need three things:

- `QNetworkAccessManager * manager;` -> To send us a request.
- `QNetworkRequest request;` -> what type of demand? get, post, ...
- `QNetworkReply`. -> What's the answer?

for more detail:

- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#details
- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkrequest.html#details
- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html#details

for example:

.cpp

```cpp
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
    QObject::connect(manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished,
        this, [=](QNetworkReply *reply) {
            if (reply->error()) {
                qDebug() << reply->errorString();
                return;
            }

            QString answer = reply->readAll();

            qDebug() << answer;
        }
    );
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    request.setUrl(QUrl("http://url"));
    manager->get(request);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
    delete manager;
}
```

.h file

```cpp
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager;
    QNetworkRequest request;
```

**EDIT LAMBDA SLOT:**
if not use lambda SIGNAL SLOT.

Discribe one slot in your .h file
for example:

```cpp
private slots:
    void managerFinished(QNetworkReply *reply);
```

in .cpp constructor replace lambda to

```cpp
QObject::connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
    this, SLOT(managerFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
```

now in your slot:

```cpp
void MainWindow::managerFinished(QNetworkReply *reply) {
    if (reply->error()) {
        qDebug() << reply->errorString();
        return;
    }

    QString answer = reply->readAll();

    qDebug() << answer;
}
```

Comment: do you know about SIGNAL and SLOT ? 
if not, first of all http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html go to study this.

Comment: Thanks! There are so many documentation and example for QT, wow! I can't believe it's an open source.   I didn't understand one thing: ::finished,
        this, [=](QNetworkReply *reply)

Comment: this is lambda signal slot. 
https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax search lambda

Comment: I have a problem... This API call using https and I found SSL err

Comment: qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_new
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
"Error creating SSL context ()"   -  I download OpenSSL and I put libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll in project directory but it still not works

Comment: I solved. I put those dll into GT bin directory. They were in bad position. A question, if I would to put this call into a function that i call every 10 seconds to update data, have I to declare a private method in .h and put the code into it in .cpp file and maybe using Sleep() and calling it recursively? And another question: I don'y want button in my application, I just would to open it, call api and print value and update every 10 seconds

Comment: it is not recursive. forget recursive. you can use QTimer http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html. set interval your QTimer object and every timeout SLOT send request using manager.

Comment: You don't need to hold `QNetworkRequest` as class member. Simply do:
manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("https://www.google.com")));

Answer (score 7):

I just managed to get HTTP requests working.

This example simply downloads google HTML page and prints its content to the terminal.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "main.h"

MyObject::MyObject(QApplication* app) {
    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(app);
}

void MyObject::TestConnection() const {
auto status = connect(manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished,
                      this, &MyObject::ReplyFinished);
    qDebug() << "Connection status:" << status;

    manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("https://www.google.com")));
}

void MyObject::ReplyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply) {
    QString answer = reply->readAll();
    qDebug() << answer;
    QApplication::quit();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    auto *app = new QApplication(argc, argv);
    auto myObject = new MyObject(app);
    myObject->TestConnection();
    return QApplication::exec();
}
```

**main.h**

```
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkReply>
#include <QApplication>

class MyObject : public QObject {
Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyObject(QApplication* application);
    void TestConnection() const;
    static void ReplyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply);

    QNetworkAccessManager *manager;
};
```

To compile this on **Linux** with **CMake**, use following **CMakeLists.txt**:

```sh
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(http)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON) # important

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp main.h)

find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Network REQUIRED) # important

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Network) # important
```

Comment: Are you realy tested and make it work? I dont think so..

Comment: @Tazoleladze Yes, I did. Why?