# Qt infinite loop in another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I am trying to setup an infinite loop in another thread. The purpose is to download some data from an URL, send the data to the main thread and sleep for some seconds:

```
DataFetcher::DataFetcher(QUrl url, int fetchRateSec) :
    url {url},
    fetchRateSec {fetchRateSec}
{

}

void DataFetcher::run()
{
    QNetworkAccessManager* manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
    QObject::connect(manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, this, &DataFetcher::onReply);

    while (true) {
        QNetworkRequest req;
        req.setUrl(url);
        manager->get(req);
        qDebug() << "run";
        sleep(fetchRateSec);
    }
}


void DataFetcher::onReply(QNetworkReply* reply)
{
    qDebug() << "repl";
    emit fetched(reply->readAll());
}

class DataFetcher : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    DataFetcher(QUrl, int);
    void run() override;
signals:
    void fetched(QString);
private:
    const QUrl url;
    const int fetchRateSec;   
private slots:
    void onReply(QNetworkReply*);
};
```

But `onReply` is never called.

It is interesting because the `qDebug` in the `while` loop is executed as it should.

Im a bit nooby with QT so i might have missed something regarding how to connect the slots / signals but i think i got it right following some other examples.

It looks about right from the accepted answer in [How do I write a Qt HTTP GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46943134/how-do-i-write-a-qt-http-get-request)

what could be the problem here?

Comment: I'm not sure it's related to your problems yet, but there's really no need for a background thread, loop, or sleep. Qt is event-driven, so you can just create a [timer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html) in the main thread, and connect its [timeout signal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#timeout) to a function that makes your request. Then the signal indicating the [completion of the request](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#finished) can be connected to any other slot you'd like.

Comment: It seems that your thread immediately sleeps once the ```get``` is done. When your thread is slept, no signals and slots would be sent and received. Instead, use a QTimer as @bnaecker suggested correctly.

Comment: QNetworkAccesManager works synchronously, you must enter the event loop (thread.exec()) instead of blocking the thread with the while loop

Comment: @bnaecker Alright, that sounds like a better route for accomplishing what im trying to do. Thank you. Could you post that comment as an answer so that i can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the discussion in the comments, it seems like the whole business of threading is not needed.

One of Qt's strongest attributes is that it is event-driven. You generally create a program by describing what you want to happen (*slots*) in response to certain events (*signals*). Explicitly waiting or sleeping is very rare in Qt-based applications (usually only testing), and is generally considered a no-no in event-driven development.

For your specific problem, a solution might look like this. You can create a [`QTimer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html) in the main thread and connect its [timeout signal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#timeout) to a function to make your HTTP request. You can then connect a slot to the [`QNetworkAccessManager::finished` signal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#finished), which will run when your response completes. All of this can take place in the main thread, relying on the thread's event loop to manage the callbacks. No need to manage a separate thread yourself, and no looping, sleeping, blocking, or anything like that.