# Ad hoc application layer protocol in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, http, networking, network-programming

I want to create a client and server in Qt that communicate without http/https. To start, I looked up examples of http clients in Qt with the goal of removing the http parts and replacing them with my own application layer. I started with [this example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtnetwork-http-example.html) and [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46943134/how-do-i-write-a-qt-http-get-request). In neither case can I figure out what code says "this is an http request."

Networking in Qt seems to require passing a QNetworkRequest to a QNetworkAccessManager. When I look at the [QNetworkRequest documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qnetworkrequest.html), everything feels designed for http. Even if this class can be used for non-http requests, I am worried I might be paying an unnecessary price for this abstraction.

As an example, suppose I want the client to send the message "cat" to the server. Instead of inserting "cat" into an http payload and passing it to the transport layer, I could just send "cat" with the understanding that the server knows how to interpret the bits.

How do I send messages over the internet with a non-http application layer in Qt?

Comment: Use a plain [QTcpSocket](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtcpsocket.html) / [QTcpServer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtcpserver.html) and implement your own protocol.

Comment: Important detail: TCP/IP is byte stream. There are no "packets". You have to indicate packet boundaries _somehow_. Length prefix. Delimiter (like newline). Just disconnect, even.