How to make an HTTP request using QTcpSocket?
I need to implement a custom HTTP client using QTcpSocket. However, I always getting this response:
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad request
Content-length: 90
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

<html><body><h1>400 Bad request</h1>\nYour browser sent an invalid request.\n</body></html>\n

This is the main part of my code
this->socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
this->socket->connectToHost(QHostAddress("172.64.155.249"), 80); // stackoverflow.com
if (!this->socket->waitForConnected()) {
    qDebug() << this->socket->errorString();
    exit(1);
}

auto dataToSendToServer = QString("GET /questions HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: stackoverflow.com\r\n\r\n");
socket->write(IntToArray(dataToSendToServer.size()));
socket->write(dataToSendToServer.toUtf8());
if (!socket->waitForBytesWritten()) {
    qDebug() << this->socket->errorString();
    exit(2);
}

connect(socket, &QIODevice::readyRead, this, [&](){
    auto receivedData = socket->readAll();
    qDebug() << QString(receivedData);
});

I also using this function to send an integer value as an array
QByteArray IntToArray(qint32 source) {
    QByteArray temp;
    QDataStream data(&temp, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    data << source;
    return temp;
}

I tried to send different data, but response is always the same.
Can you please help me to get 200?

Try using telnet 185.15.59.224 80 (check syntax for port) and then entering GET / .   If this works keep trying more of your original request.

This question is similar to: What, at the bare minimum, is required for an HTTP request?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. See also the similar https://stackoverflow.com/q/9233316/238704

socket->write(IntToArray(dataToSendToServer.size())); What is this supposed to do, and why do you believe it's needed? What happens if you drop this line? it doesn't make sense. You are basically sending garbage to the server.

@IgorTandetnik I thought I also need to send data size, but even without it I am getting the same response.

Are you sure 151.101.65.69 is the right address? That's not what stackoverflow.com resolves to on my machine.  Why don't you pass the actual host name in connectToHost?

@RomanPodymov Your HTTP request itself is fine, but if you read the HTTP specs (RFC 1945 for HTTP/1.0 and RFCs 2616 and 7230-7235 for HTTP/1.1), you will see that HTTP messages are not prefixed with the message size, which is why you need to get rid of the socket->write(IntToArray(dataToSendToServer.size())); call. What is 151.101.65.69? That is not StackOverflow (which resolves to 104.18.32.7 on my machine).  Could it be some kind of proxy on your network?

@IgorTandetnik Took this IP from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15772575/2229783

@RemyLebeau Thanks, took this IP from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15772575/2229783

@RomanPodymov that answer is 11 years old. IP addresses can change over time. Don't rely on posted IPs. Just get the current IP for yourself. Or, simply pass in the hostname, like Igor said, and let the QTcpSocket get the current IP for you, eg: this->socket->connectToHost(QStringLiteral("stackoverflow.com"), 80); That being said, HTTP/1.0 is really old, so you might consider upgrading your request to HTTP/1.1 at least. But, why aren't you using Qt's built-in HTTP support instead? See https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtnetwork-http-example.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46943134/

@RemyLebeau I think the problem was in socket->write(IntToArray(dataToSendToServer.size())), I should not send it, thanks for your help.
